# No graph shown on Microsoft Mathematics

Tags: math-software

When I try to graph this formula, $$y=\sum^x_{n=1}[n*\sum^n_{m=1}\sin(\frac{m}{n})]$$, the graph shows nothing.

I thought it is possible that I input it in wrongly or the software can't solve this kind of summation equation but when I try with other equation like this, $$y=\sum^x_{n=1}[n*\sum^n_{m=1}(\frac{m}{n})]$$, the software is able to graph it.

Why is it unable to solve my first equation?

Comment: I suppose that you need a discrete plot of $y$ as a function of $x$ which is an integer.

Comment: Is there any reason why the software can't plot that graph?